# Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml:

Tags: flutter

So I'am making just a hangman game app on flutter and I wanted to add a splash screen to it with an image. I'am sure I have the correct identation in the pub spec.yaml,also the correct path and I don't know why it keeps getting me error. Can you help me please?

[image]

Her is my splash screen code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:splashscreen/splashscreen.dart';
import '../../main.dart';
import 'package:hangman/utilities/constants.dart';

class LoadingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _LoadingScreen();
  }
}

class _LoadingScreen extends State<LoadingScreen> {
  CustomColors colors = CustomColors();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //loading();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SplashScreen(
          loaderColor: colors.secondColor,
          seconds: 1000,
          navigateAfterSeconds: const MyHomePage(title: 'HANGMAN'),
          backgroundColor: colors.mainColor,
          title: Text(
            'HANGMAN',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 50.0,
                color: colors.secondColor),
          ),
          image: const Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/hangmanLoading.png'),),
          photoSize: 150.0,
        ));
  }
}
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml:

```
name: hangman
description: A new Flutter project.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.18.4 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  splashscreen: ^1.3.5

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  #uses-material-design: true
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/hangmanLoading.png/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

And here is my project skeleton:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the "/" from the end of this line in the pubspec.yaml

```
- assets/images/hangmanLoading.png/
```

Comment: I can't believe that was the entire mistake for it. I feel really dumb about it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome. :) Please, accept as an answer. Thank you.